# Getting a column name based on the name and its values in an array in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an input with uploads `CSV` file and a function which reads the file with the following result.

```
[[Names, Phone, area],[content1],[content2], [content3],[content1],[content2], [content3]]
```

For example I would only like to get phone number with all phone number, keeping in mind the phone position might change.

Comment: Uh, no, this is absolutely not a JSON structure

Comment: Is your result one big string, an array of strings, or an array of undefined variables?

Comment: Arrays as I have displayed above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly:

```
let arr = [["Names","Phone","area"],["Matt","123-456-7890","here"],["Gerald","098-765-4321","there"]];
let phoneColIndex = arr[0].indexOf("Phone");
let phoneNumbers = arr.slice(1).map(entry => entry[phoneColIndex]);
```

Comment: It works, I did solve it using lodash with this   `arr.slice(1).forEach(element => { var ziped =  _.zipObject(arr.[0], element););`

Answer (score 0):

I also manage to fix it using `lodash` with `zip`

```
arr.slice(1).forEach(element => { 
var ziped = _.zipObject(arr.[0], element););
```